# Can I use a file descriptor opened by the paren process in the child after calling any exec function in C?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, posix

Suppose I have a process `p` that uses a file descriptor, for example an unnamed pipe, to communicate to his parent process `p1`.

Suppose `p` calls `fork()` to create a child process `c` which right after the `fork()` calls one of the `exec` family function.

By default parent's file descriptors are duplicated to the child even when using `exec`. So `c` should be able to communicate with `p1`, having its parent `p` opened a file descriptor to `p1`.

How can I get that file descriptor in the C source code of `c` child process if the variable corresponding to that file descriptor is defined only in `p` (and `p1`)?

Just to give an example of what I mean, the following is the code for `p` and `p1`

```
//p1 process
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
pid_t p_pid, c_pid;

p_pid = fork();
if(p_pid == 0) // p process
{
/* p_pid closes up input side of pipe */
    close(fd[0]);
    c_pid = fork();
    if (c_pid)==0 //c child process
    {
        exec("execution/child/process"...); 
    }
    else
    {
        ...// do p process parenting stuff      
    }

 }
 else
 {
     /* Parent p1 process closes up output side of pipe */
     close(fd[1]);
 }
```

Now the `"execution/child/process"` has its own source code and I cannot use the variable `fd` to communicate with `p1` since it is not defined but the file descriptor should exist: so how to reference it and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default parent's file descriptors are duplicated to the child even
>   when using `exec`. So `c` should be able to communicate with `p1`, having
>   its parent `p` opened a file descriptor to `p1`.

Yes.  The main proviso is that the file descriptor is not set close-on-exec.

> How can I get that file descriptor in the C source code of `c` child
>   process if the variable corresponding to that file descriptor is
>   defined only in `p` (and `p1`)?

- You can `dup2()` the file descripor onto a well-known number, such as stdin's (0), stdout's (1), or stderr's (2), or some other number that parent and child code agree upon.
- You can pass the file descriptor number to the child as an argument.
- You can write the number to a file from which the child subsequently reads it.
- As a special case of the previous, you can set up a pipe from the parent to the child's stdin, and send the number to the child over the pipe.

Those are not the only possibilities, but I think they cover all of the easiest and best ones.  Note well that the first is the only one that does not depend on the cooperation of the child.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. What do you mean by `first is the only one that does not depend on the cooperation of the child`? They should know both a common value (for example put in a common header). Isn't the second one requiring less "coupling"?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi, by duping the file descriptor onto one of the child's standard streams, you can cause the child to use it (for whatever purposes it ordinarily uses that stream) without doing anything special or even being aware.  This is how the shell performs redirection.

Comment: Using a different well-known number is another story, as is the case where the child is aware that it has for one of its standard streams a special file descriptor inherited from the parent that it must use a certain way.